# Not able to state with react typed.js callbacks

Tags: reactjs, typed.js

I'm trying to update a counter located in the state every time the type string changes with this node module. When I'm attaching the `preStringTyped` function to the  component, the function (the `alert` located in the `preStringTyped`) triggers only once.

Here's the module: [https://github.com/ssbeefeater/react-typed](https://www.google.com/search?q=typed%20react&oq=typed%20react&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i60l3.1835j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Here's my code - you can ignore the `randomlySelectElements` and the `displayTweets` function, what matters here is the `preStringTyped` and what is inside the `return()`.

```
  preStringTyped = () => {
    alert("typed")
  }


  randomlySelectElements = (number, array) => {
    let shuffedArray = _.shuffle(array);
    let selectedEle = shuffedArray.slice(0, number);
    return selectedEle;
  }


  displayTweets = () => {
    if(!this.state.rawData){
      return null
    }else{
      let getRandomTweetsStrings = () => {
          return this.randomlySelectElements(10, this.state.rawData)
          .map((ele, index) => {
            return ele.masterData.randomString
          })
      }

      return (
        <ReactTyped
          loop
          typeSpeed={50}
          backSpeed={20}
          strings={
              getRandomTweetsStrings()
          }
          smartBackspace
          backDelay={1}
          fadeOutDelay={100}
          loopCount={0}
          showCursor
          cursorChar="|"
          onBegin={this.preStringTyped()}
        />
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `preStringTyped` callback (not `onBegin`) that will be triggered before each string is typed. Also in your code you emidiatly execute the function `this.preStringTyped()` but you should pass it as a reference to the callback property (`preStringTyped={this.preStringTyped}`). Your code should be like this

```js
        <ReactTyped
          loop
          typeSpeed={50}
          backSpeed={20}
          strings={
              getRandomTweetsStrings()
          }
          smartBackspace
          backDelay={1}
          fadeOutDelay={100}
          loopCount={0}
          showCursor
          cursorChar="|"
          preStringTyped={this.preStringTyped} // <- not onBegin={this.preStringTyped()}
        />
```